# Graph Coloring Problem

Tags: graphs, colorings

Can solutions to the graph coloring problem be used in the prison system to keep known enemies apart with the goal of reducing violence?

Comment: Can you give a simple example to further clarify your intention?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear exactly what level you're asking the question at.

*In principle*, you could set up a graph where the vertices are prisoners, there's an edge between any two prisoners who need to be kept separate, and each prison corresponds to a colour. *In practice*, there are probably too many prisoners in any reasonably sized country for this to be a computationally tractable approach (though the conflict graph would probably be rather sparse), there are more constraints on the system that would be hard to model in this graph-colouring approach, and two prisoners getting into a fight could cause a re-colouring that might cause a large proportion of the prison population to be moved, which is neither feasible nor desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in theory, assuming the prison has $n$ separated blocks.

Let each vertex be a prisoner, let each hostile relationship be a graph edge between their two respective vertices and color the graph.

The color of each vertex determines what block the prisoner ends up in, no two prisoners that have a hostile relationship will end up in the same block.

Note that this isn't very useful in practice without other requirements, as for example blocks have limited capacity.